# Generate the infobulle with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I need to generate the infobulle for a button in Silverlight with C#.
I have this code :

```
<Button x:Name="ctr" Content="Contrôler" Foreground="White" Margin="10 0" Click="ctr_Click"
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
    <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Contrôler">
    </Grid>
    </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

but I need the change the infobulle in C# like this

```
if (message =="OK") infobulle-->controle the page else infobulle-->controle
```

Comment: title, formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
if (message =="OK") {
 ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this.ctr, new TextBlock() { Text = "controle the page" });
}
else{
 ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this.ctr, new TextBlock() { Text = "controle" });
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.